# How do i keep taking inputs from multiple users until a specific user says a particular keyword (discord.js)?

Tags: discord.js

So I've been trying to make an auction bot on discord. I've figured out how to handle a single item, but I'm having issues regarding bundles.

My goal - Let the user info any/all items when auctioning a bundle till he says the keyword 'done'. The bot stores the url of the first message (embed sent by the bot) and then does nothing till the user says done. The two users are 1. the user himself, 2. the bot who's item(s) he wants to auction.

I tried using the message collector but the bot straight up ignores it. After searching around on the web and trying to adapt to my situation, the closest thing i found is using async/await with awaitMessages while inside a for loop. After that failed too, i tried to use a chain of then() with the awaitMessages. Here's my code snippet. Any help is appreciated.

```
let flg =0 
if(arguments[3] === 'bundle'){
    message.channel.send('Say `done` when you have info-ed all your pokemons')
            
    await message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === '666956518511345684' || m.author.id === message.author.id, {time : 30000, errors : ['time']}).then(col1 => {
        if (col1.first().author.id === '666956518511345684')
            details.poke = col1.first().url
            }).then(col2 => {
                   if (col2.first().author.id === message.author.id)
                      while(flg = 0){
                           if (col2.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'done')
                              flg = 1
                      }
                })
```

Comment: You can use the filter passed into `awaitMessages()` to only accept messages that equal the keyword

Comment: @Elitezen do you mean something like `let filter = m => m.author.id === '<bot's id>' || (m.author.id === message.author.id && m.content.toLowerCase() === 'done')`
If so, it wont work since `awaitMessages()` accepts only the first input as far as i know and i want the first input to be the bot's input, to store it's url. After that the user can type whatever he wishes and the code will do nothing, until the user says the keyword "done". When the keyword is input, the bot sends an embed.

Comment: You can configure `awaitMessages()` to take multiple inputs and ignore bot messages. I'll post an answer shortly

Comment: You can use a mongo database to store the status of the auction and change it when a keyword is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried message collector once again and i made it work somehow. Here's how :

```
let i = 0
let filter = m => {m.author.id === '<Bot's id>' || m.author.id === message.author.id}
let collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {time : 30000})
collector.on('collect', m => {
     if (m.author.id === '<bot's id>' && i === 0){
          details.poke = m.url
          i = 1
     }
     if (m.author.id === message.author.id && m.content.toLowerCase() === 'done'){
          collector.stop()
     }
})
collector.on('end', col => { //code here })
```

The variable `i` is  a flag, since i only want the url of the first message sent by the bot. It can be removed/more flags can be added up to your needs/requirements.
Lemme know if you need anymore help regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Have the collector ignore bot messages, take multiple inputs and check for message content. Once time runs out, or the max input has been reached, the collection of messages will be returned.

```
if(arguments[3] === 'bundle'){
   message.channel.send('Say `done` when you have info-ed all your pokemons')
   const filter = m => {
      return !m.user.bot && ['666956518511345684', message.author.id].includes(m.author.id) && m.content.toLowerCase() === 'done';
   }
   message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
      // Take a max of 5 inputs for example
      max: 5
      time: 30000,
      errors: ['time']
   }).then(collected => {
      // Your code
   })
}
```

Documentation on [TextChannel#awaitMessages()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the issue is idk what the maximum number of messages can be. I tried removing the max property for this reason. Anyhoo, I found a code working for me, thanks for your answer too.

Comment: Without a max option the collector will collect messages until the timer runs out. Glad you found the solution, Goodluck